# Vb.net Updating excel formula with references to other workbooks

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to update some formulas from one workbook, to another workbook.  Everything is working great until I run into a formula that has a reference to another workbook.  For example a formula like this `=IF(ISERROR(W!Var1),0,W!Var2)`  It will prompt me to open this workbook, I am assuming so that it can evaluate the formula.  So my question is this.  Is there a way for me to handle these situations on the fly, so if there is a workbook reference needed it will prompt me and then save it to memory?  Because if I have more than one cell that contains these formulas it will prompt me to open the referenced workbook for every cell that contains the link.  Alternatively, is there a way that I can just push my formula into the cell without having excel evaluate it?

So in my code I have this line which works for any value that doesn't contain a workbook reference. `TheRange.RefersToRange.FormulaR1C1 = RangeFormula`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you refer to `Worksheets` (each of the "tabs" in a given Excel file), the `Workbook` is the whole file. The popping-up message appears when the referred Worksheet cannot be found. Example: `range.Value = "=sheet5!A3"` (in a Workbook having just "sheet1", "sheet2" and "sheet3"). If you want to avoid this message (although bear in mind that the Worksheet is not there and thus the calculations will be wrong anyway), you can write:

```
excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Where `excelApp` is the `Excel.Application` you are currently using.

Comment: that worked.  Just turning off the alerts worked for me because I did not have to evaluate it.  I'm just basically updating values and exiting.

Comment: @joeb OK. But bear in mind that this flag avoids most of the (error/warning) messages to be triggered.